# RecyclerView.Holder looses information about animation if it's scrolled away (notice it is not recycled)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm implementing an recyclerview and an adapter on top of that (obviously). In the ViewHolders I have an ImageView that is clickable. This imageView uses an animation that is done in XML and can be a "filled heart" and "unfilled heart". When enabling it fills the heart from bottom up. When disabling it breaks the heart and the heart returns to an "unfilled heart".

How I create my "bug":

1. Open app
2. "Heart" my item (this is saved in a DB and loaded each time you open the app later). This will activate the animation to fill the heart, the heart will stay filled.
3. If I scroll just so I can't see my item and then back up the heart is "unfilled". The item never got to the recycling part, it just got out of vision. The "unfilled heart" is the base-state of the animation so to say.
4. If I now click the heart the "break"-animation (i.e. unheart) activates as it should. But it goes from unfilled heart -> break-animation -> unfilled heart.

**Note:**

1. I don't want my "filled-heart"-state to turn back just because the view goes out of "visibility".
2. The state of filled heart is there if my view is recycled and then returned by binding.

My RecyclerView.Holder functions.

```
fun onTrackClick(tracking : Boolean){
    Log.d(TAG, "Clling onTrack!")
    val stateSet = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked * if (tracking) 1 else -1)
    btn.setImageState(stateSet, true);
}

fun bind(item: Media, viewActions: onViewSelectedListener){
    if(item.imgpath.isNotEmpty()){
        image.loadImg("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${item.imgpath}") // 342 vs 500
    }

    id = item.tmdbid
    viewActions.getSingleMedia(item.tmdbid)
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.subscribe({ singleMedia ->
                onTrackClick(true)
                tracking = true}, {throwable -> onTrackClick(false)})
    Log.d(TAG, "In here for ${item.tmdbid}")
    title.text = item.name
    rating.text = "${item.rating}"

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        viewActions.onTracking(item)
        tracking = !tracking
        onTrackClick(tracking)
    }
    super.itemView.setOnClickListener { viewActions.onItemSelected(item)}   // Only need ID.
}
```

And then my ImageView that is getting animated:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_button_tracker_media_item"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:transitionName="HEART"
    android:src="@drawable/asl_trimclip_heart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rating"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />
```

And the animations:

```
    <animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/liked"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vd_trimclip_heart_full"
    android:state_checked="true"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/not_liked"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vd_trimclip_heart_empty"/>

  <transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/avd_trimclip_heart_fill"
    android:fromId="@id/not_liked"
    android:toId="@id/liked"/>

  <transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/avd_trimclip_heart_break"
    android:fromId="@id/liked"
    android:toId="@id/not_liked"/>

</animated-selector>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your problem is actually not setting the final state of filled hard, whenever you have two states in a `RecyclerView` you must not forget to set the "special" case (in this situation, the filled heart).

Meaning, if you check for a value to your model, you must always set the current state, a simple example would be:

```
onBindViewHolder(..) {
  // The View.GONE is the easly forgot state
  imageView.visibility = if(someModel.isShowImageView()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE) 
}
```

Simply put, after you finish your animation you should set the imageView to its final state (filled heart), or else when the animation is reset (out of view) you are displayed the initial state.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this solution myself but I was hoping there would be a more clean one available. 

It worked though so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Guess you prefer 50% of an answer to no answer at all, so here's my 2 cents:

Your data has two states: heart filled and heart unfilled. These two states should be reflected in the `View` by showing different drawable resources.

So basically you have to use two `View` types in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation. To do so, you need to override `getItemViewType()` and return the correct View type for the current state and in `onCreateViewHolder()` you need to set the drawable resource depending on the `View` type.

If you "heart" or "unheart" a `RecyclerView` item, its state has to change. You are already updating the underlying data (else the state would not be shown correctly after the `View` is recycled). So all that is left to do is to call `notifyItemChanged()` on the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Either you postpone this until after the animation has finished (e.g. by using the postDelayed() method on an android.os.Handler instance ) or you try to implement your own `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` (but only if the other approach looks bad because of flickering drawables)

Comment: Note to self: update Android Studio and really start learning Kotlin!

Comment: As mentioned above I was thinking about this kind of solution myself but was hoping there'd be a more clean one. Don't like this approach but it works so it'll have to do. Thanks! :)

Edit: Yes you should, Kotlin is so much more fun to program in!